# props value not sending the updated value from parent to child component in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a parent child component. The issue I am facing here is that validation field which I am sending as a prop from parent to child doesn't get updated the first time I click on submit button in child component. For example, when I submit the form on the child component it checks the form validation using the checkValidation method in the parent component. Let's say the form validation was true when it was submitted but in the console this.validation still shows false in the child component and when I click on submit again, then in the console this.validation return true. So the this.validation value changes the second time on clicking the submit button. Please help me solve this issue

parent component

```
<template>  
  <UserDetails
      ref="user_details"
      :validation="validation"
      @checkValidation="checkValidation"
      />                  
</template>

<script>
  import UserDetails from 'views/my_account/users/edit.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      UserDetails,
    },
    data: function () {
      return {        
        validation: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      checkValidation() {
        var valid = false;
        var that = this;
        valid = this.$refs["user_details"].$refs.userForm.validate()
        this.validation = valid
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

child component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-form :model='user' ref='userForm'>
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right">
            <v-text-field
              label='User Name'
              required
              v-model='user.name'>
            </v-text-field>
          </v-flex> 
        </v-layout>       
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-btn @click.prevent='submit'>Save</v-btn>
        </v-layout>
    </v-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
  props: ['validation'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      user: {
        name: ''
      }
    };
  },
  
  methods: {    
    submit() {
      this.$emit('checkValidation');
      console.log(this.validation)
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Events are not like calling a method on an object, they are asynchronous. When your child logs the current value of `this.validation`, it has not yet been modified by the event handler, because the event handler has not been executed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
//child component
  submit() {
  this.$emit('checkValidation');
  this.$nextTick(()=>{console.log(this.validation)})
},
```

for further details I recommend the following
[article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2019/02/22/what-is-nexttick-in-vue-and-when-you-need-it)
[documention](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

the article should answer most of your doubts

Comment: How can I use the updated value of this.validation. Something like

if (this.validation) {
 console.log("true")
}
else {
console.log("Hello")
}

Comment: @user12763413 yes within the callback function it should work

Answer (score -1):

If your child component has the form, why is validation not done on the child component. You can then emit the "Saved" event when the form is valid, pick that up in the parent and do what you want and you know the child is valid at that point? removes all those ref points.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, put a comment if you disagree. It makes little sense for form validation to not be in the component with the form.